# Tax implication when receiving Bitcoin gift from foreign relative?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, gift-tax, cryptocurrency

Does the recipient has to pay tax, or report receiving the Bitcoin?

receiving: US, sending: China.

Edit: receiving gift.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Question like this require a country tag, and specifically, to note both countries involved. Tax and gift laws are different in each country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the money is a gift.

For intangible gifts from foreign persons, the gift is reportable if it is over $100,000 in fair market value. If the amount is less than this, the gift does not have to be reported. If the gift is coming from a foreign corporation or organization, any amount over about $15,000 is reportable. [The IRS has a web page with guidance on this form.](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/gifts-from-foreign-person) Note that payments for tuition or medical expenses are not considered gifts or income and do not have to be reported.

Gifts from foreign persons are not considered income and are not subject to income tax.

Comment: Thank you! in this case, are there any other tax needs to be paid besides the income tax?

Comment: @HelinWang Not as far as I know.

Comment: @HelinWang -  note, the answer specifically states no income tax is due.

Comment: Note that this does not mean that you do not have to pay income tax if/when you sell or otherwise dispose of the bitcoin! This just means no taxes are due from the transfer of the bitcoin to you. Money from selling or benefit from trading a gift is usually income.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, selling things that belong to you does not generate "income".

Comment: @FiveBagger It does if you sell them for more than your tax basis. The same is true if you barter them for other things of value.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, if the sale was for more than declared fair market value at the time of the gift, then it would be a capital gain, not income.

Comment: @FiveBagger First, capital gains are a type of income. Second, you are (unfortunately) incorrect about how the basis on a gift is calculated. I wish you were right, because I have some bitcoins that I bought for $15 that are now worth over $6,000 and I'd love to gift them to people to avoid having to pay capital gains taxes on that $15->$6,000 appreciation, but that's not how it works. (I suspect you're thinking of inheritance.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on jurisdiction, but generally: you pay tax not on cash income, but on value received. So, in case of someone gifting you bitcoin you the local tax situation applies SIMILAR TO SOMEONE GIFTING YOU MONEY - with the value of the bitcoin (as per exchanges) at the time of the gift.

This is in line with normal tax laws, similar to someone gifting you a bar of gold.

Depending on value a gift tax has to be paid. Between US and China it is time to ask tax advisors.

Comment: Thanks! It seems in US the person receiving money from a foreign person does not have to pay tax, but need to report if above some threshold: https://www.irs.gov/businesses/gifts-from-foreign-person